# How to specify Rust lifetime when returning item that lives longer than iterator

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write an iterator that returns string slices from byte array.  I'm having trouble specifying the lifetimes to indicate that the slice can live longer than the iterator.

A simplified test case would be:

```
struct StrStream<'a> {
    data: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> StrStream<'a> {
    fn new(data: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self { data }
    }

    fn cstr(&'a mut self, len: usize) -> Option<&'a str> {
        Some(self.data.get(0..len).unwrap())
    }
}

struct MyIterator<'a> {
    i: u32,
    stream: &'a mut StrStream<'a>,
}

impl<'a> MyIterator<'a> {
    fn new(stream: &'a mut StrStream<'a>) -> Self {
        Self { i: 1, stream }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.i += 1;
        if self.i < 10 {
            return Some(self.stream.cstr(self.i as usize).unwrap());
        }
        return None;
    }
}

#[test]
fn iterates_tokens() {
    let mut stream = StrStream::new("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    let myiter = MyIterator::new(&mut stream);
    for item in myiter {
        println!(">>>{:?}", item);
    }
}
```

This fails to compile with the error below.  Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> xxx/src/tests.rs:32:25
   |
26 | impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
29 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
32 |             return Some(self.stream.cstr(self.i as usize).unwrap());
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

Comment: You might want to look into the [lending iterator](https://docs.rs/lending-iterator/latest/lending_iterator/#) crate, and either use the lib or take inspiration from their source

Comment: What about [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c94fbfafd117d469bb81b779cba6c5f8)?

Comment: That works @ChayimFriedman.  Not sure how I missed it - many thanks!